# routing in my mvc project is not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

i ve created a new mvc project. after than i added old web forms content in it. in my old web forms pages or configrution, something prevents routing in my project and /Home/Index is not working.

but i really couldn,t find any thing wrong. please help.

this is my global.asax part and i didnt make any changes in following default classes

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
```

as i sad i didnt change any thing in above classes and this is my registerRoutes method content

```
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.aspx/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
          );
        }
```

and the parts of my web config

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5"  defaultLanguage="c#" optimizeCompilations="true">
  <assemblies>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.Common, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Drawing, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Xml, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Windows.Forms, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.DirectoryServices, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Drawing.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B03F5F7F11D50A3A"/>
    <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization.Design, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="WindowsBase, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
    <add assembly="office, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>
    <add assembly="Microsoft.Vbe.Interop, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71E9BCE111E9429C"/>

  </assemblies>

  ...

  <namespaces>
    <add namespace="System.Web.Helpers" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Ajax" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Mvc.Html" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.Routing" />
    <add namespace="System.Web.WebPages" />
  </namespaces>

  ...

  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
       <remove name="Session"/>
       <add name="Session" type="System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateModule"/>
       <remove name="RequestControlModule"/>
       <add name="RequestControlModule" preCondition="managedHandler" type="RequestControlModule" />
       <add name="UrlRoutingModule-4.0" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule" preCondition="" />
  </modules>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to RegisterRoute method to following:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.MapRoute(null,
               "{controller}/{action}",
                new
                {
                    controller = "Home",
                    action = "Index"    
                }
               );

               routes.MapRoute(
                  "Default", // Route name
                   "",        // URL with parameters
                   new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }  // Parameter defaults
               );
    }
```

Comment: beside my method is auto generated by VS 2012 and you claim that it is wrong? your answer does not work but can u please explain why would u think this may be a solution?

Comment: please provide listing of your Index method in your HomeController class. The answer above is not the one you need I will replace it with the right one as we figure it out. It should look something like this: public class HomeController : Controller {
public ViewResult Index() {
return View();
}
}